# Tensorflow reuse when inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Does tensorflow need to set the reuse ==True when finish training and inference?
I have a network like this:

```
def __build_net(self,placeholder,reuse=False):
         with tf.variable_scope('siamse',reuse=reuse):
             layer = tf.layers.dense(placeholder,3000,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
             layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

             embedding= tf.layers.dense(layer,300,activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu)
             print('Siamse Net has built',flush=True)
         return embedding
```

And I create two network share same parameter:

```
self.embedding1=self.__build_net(self.centers_placeholder)
self.embedding2=self.__build_net(self.neighbors_placeholder,reuse=True)
```

I used this network to generate embeddings of some kind of data.

My question is: Do I need to set the reuse to True when doing inference(generate embedding) like this:

```
       with tf.Session() as sess:
        self.saver.restore(sess,self.store_path+self.model_type+'_model_'+str(self.model_num)+'_'+str(self.center_size)+'_'+str(self.neighbor_size)+'.ckpt')
        embedding = self.__build_net(self.centers_placeholder,reuse=True)
        embeddings = sess.run(embedding,feed_dict = {self.centers_placeholder : data})
```

Or like this:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        self.saver.restore(sess,self.store_path+self.model_type+'_model_'+str(self.model_num)+'_'+str(self.center_size)+'_'+str(self.neighbor_size)+'.ckpt')
        embedding = self.__build_net(self.centers_placeholder,reuse=False)
        embeddings = sess.run(embedding,feed_dict = {self.centers_placeholder : data})
```

And then, When set the variable scope, do I need to give a name to each layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No....`reuse` means whether you need to use a previously defined variable.

Say, you've created a variable called 'foo/v':

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    print(v.name)   ---> foo/v:0
```

Running the following will give:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])   ---> gives error as name 'foo/v' exists
    print(v1.name) 
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=False):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])   ---> gives error as name 'foo/v' exists
    print(v1.name) 
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    print(v1.name)   ---> foo/v:0
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    print(v1.name)   ---> foo/v:0
```

But if you run the following from the very begining:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
    print(v1.name)   ---> gives error as 'foo/v' does not exist (thus cannot be reused).
```

Thus I prefer setting `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` all the time.

For a detailed explanation, please read [How Does Variable Scope Work?](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/programmers_guide/variable_scope#how_does_variable_scope_work) from the TensorFlow official guide.

By the way, `tf.layers.batch_normalization` has a `training` option that needs to be set `False` during inference. See the explanations [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization).

Comment: Thank you very much. When I set reuse =True when inference, it not give me an error, it that mean I did not reset the graph? Do I need to reset the graph when inference?

Comment: @Yanpei No, you do not need to reset the graph. There is no such thing as reset the graph; you either use the same one, or create a new one.